# Can `sympy.codegen.ast` be used with `sympy.utilities.autowrap`?

Tags: python, sympy

I'm working on producing compiled functions using `sympy.code.autowrap`, specifically the `make_routine`, `autowrap`, and `ufuncify` functions of that module. I would like to be able to use `sympy.codegen.ast` to generate code to be wrapped. For instance:

```
import sympy as sy
from sympy.codegen.ast import (Assignment, CodeBlock, Return, Element, 
                               Pointer, Declaration, float64,
                               FunctionPrototype, FunctionDefinition)
zlist = sy.symarray('z', (5,), real=True)
d1expz = sy.apply_finite_diff(1, x_list=range(-2,3), y_list=zlist)
d2expz = sy.apply_finite_diff(2, x_list=range(-2,3), y_list=zlist)
d1p = Pointer('d1p', float64)
d2p = Pointer('d2p', float64)
d1p0 = Element('d1p', '0')
d2p0 = Element('d2p', '0')
d12fpa = FunctionPrototype(float64, 'd12funca', [d1p, d2p] + list(zlist))
body12a = [
    CodeBlock(
        Assignment(d1p0, d1expz),
        Assignment(d2p0, d2expz),
    ).cse(),
]
d12funca = FunctionDefinition.from_FunctionPrototype(
    d12fpa, body12a
)
print(sy.ccode(d12funca))
```

This results in the following C code, which looks good:

```
double d12funca(double * d1p, double * d2p, double z_0, double z_1, double z_2, double z_3, double z_4){
   x0 = (1.0/12.0)*z_0;
   x1 = -1.0/12.0*z_4;
   d1p[0] = x0 + x1 - 2.0/3.0*z_1 + (2.0/3.0)*z_3;
   d2p[0] = -x0 + x1 + (4.0/3.0)*z_1 - 5.0/2.0*z_2 + (4.0/3.0)*z_3;
}
```

`sympy.utilities.codegen.codegen` also understands this, e.g. the following produces just the kind of results you'd expect.

```
[(c_name, c_code), (h_name, c_header)] = codegen(
    ('d12func',
    [
        sy.Eq(sy.Symbol('d1'), d1expz),
        sy.Eq(sy.Symbol('d2'), d2expz)
    ]),
    language='c'
)
```

I can also produce a nicely wrapped function that does essentially the same thing as follows:

```
from sympy.utilities.autowrap import autowrap
autowrap_dir = <some path>
derivs = sy.Matrix(
    [[
        d1expz,
        d2expz
    ]]
)
dvraw = autowrap(
    expr=derivs,
    args=list(zlist),
    backend='Cython',
    tempdir=autowrap_dir,
    verbose=True
)
```

But is there any way to use the `ast` module to specify functions to be wrapped with `autowrap`? It appears that `autowrap`, `make_routine`, and `ufuncify` cannot accept arbitrary code. The expressions they take can be either lists of straightforward `sympy` expressions, or lists of `sympy.Eq` expressions (in which case the wrapped function assigns the RHS of each equality to its LHS and returns each LHS as an output argument).

The problem is that I would like to be able to wrap more involved functions including such things as for loops and branching. The `ast` module provides the tools to write such functions. But as far as I can tell, `autowrap` and `ast` don't play with each other at all.

Any thoughts on how to accomplish this would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: The sympy.codegen module is designed to be a replacement for autowrap, though its still a work in progress. Making this work may require some upstream improvements in SymPy.